# Stuck on probability question regarding correct classification of blood type

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I am trying to do this question:
The blood type distribution in the UK is: type A: $41\%$, type B: $9\%$, type AB: $4\%$, type O: $46\%$. It is
estimated that every year, $4\%$ of patients with type O are classed as having type A, $88\%$ of those with
type A are correctly classed as having type A, 4% with type B are classed as type A, and $10\%$ of those
with type AB are classed as type A.

Now a patient is classed as having type A blood. What is the probability that this is his actual blood
type (i.e. that he is correctly classed as having type A blood)?

But I am not sure what formula to use or how to even start on it. The course is currently going over Bayes theorem so I assume it is related to that but I do not see how that can be use here with this question. Can someone show what to do here?

Comment: A suggestion:  suppose there are exactly $1000$ people in the UK.  Write out exactly how many fit into each type (where a type includes things like "true type $O$ classified as $A$").  Don't worry if you have fractional people.  Now you should be able to do it numerically.  Can you see that the answer you get has to be the correct one?

Comment: Not really - I have the amounts of each, do I now take them away from the total number of people with type A?

Comment: Well, if you have all those numbers then you have the total of all those who are classified as $A$, yes?  So that's your denominator.  The numerator is the number of those who are classified as $A$ and who are in fact $A$.